# Sanic how to load confguration for test app?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, configuration, sanic

I want my test server to have a dummy config variables

I have the following fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def server():
    app.config.thing =1 #the dummy var
    return app.test_client
```

And a test

```
def test_thing(server):

    assert server.config.thing == 1
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'SanicTestClient' object has  no attribute 'config`

How do I fix  this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SanicTestClient` is a wrapper around the app - it's not the app itself. 
So simply do `assert server.app.config.thing == 1`

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Code-only answers can often be difficult to interpret.

Comment: @jakerella I think what he meant is `server` is not equivalent to an Sanic `app` instance. Maybe `server` has some other attributes that are useful to for testing purposes, but Sanic `app` is just an attribute of `server`.